# Why does it always say "undefined reference"?

Tags: c, gcc, dll, linker, mingw

(I'm on Windows.)

I'm testing a DLL I have compiled ([libsox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)) with a C program which looks this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sox.h"

int main(void) {
    char const * versionText = sox_version();
    printf(versionText);
    return 0;
}
```

The function that is defined in the DLL has the following prototype in `sox.h` (something of this contains `cdecl`):

```
LSX_RETURN_VALID_Z LSX_RETURN_PURE
char const *
LSX_API
sox_version(void);
```

Here's the problem: When I try to build the file with `gcc -lsox -o test.exe test.c` I get the following error:

```
C:\DOKUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOKALE~1\Temp\ccSS2h2z.o:test.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `sox_version'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

A word to `-lsox`: I have the library file "libsox.dll.a" in MinGW's `lib` folder. If I write `-lsoxnonsense`, then it says there is no library. That means in the shown case it finds the library. So why doesn't it want to create a link.

Comment: Did you build that library with the same compiler?  Sometimes a `_` gets prepended to symbol names.

Comment: Yes, it was the same compiler. I think the object file and the .a file contained both _sox_version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gcc -lsox -o test.exe test.c
```

You have to put your source file first:

```
gcc test.c -lsox -o test.exe
```

It is because the linker goes through the input files in order, finding undefined references and satisfying references that it saw before. So in your command line, it reads `libsox.a` (or something like that), finds undefined references (there would be none). Then, it goes to your `test.c`, finds undefined references in there, but there are no further libraries to satisfy them.

[See this answer for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/51831)

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! I found it really strange at first, because the help says "Usage: gcc [options] file...". But I think you mean the library file is an input file, too. Therefore "gcc -o test.exe test.c -lsox" also works and gcc is inconsistent with it's stated usage.