# Cannot compile simple programme that uses libxml++ because glibmmconfig.h not found

Tags: c++, libxml2

After stripping away all of the unnecessary code, this is the barebones version that refuses to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using an up-to-the-minute version of Fedora 16.  Initially, the compiler could not find even libml++/libxml++.h, because Fedora's yum puts these files in /usr/include/libxml++-2.6/libxml++.  So I got around that by creating the symlink /usr/include/libxml++ to /usr/include/libxml++-2.6/libxml++.  That stopped the compiler from complaining about not finding libxml++.h, but then, in libxml++.h there is the line

```
#include <ustring.h>
```

which again the compiler could not find.  So once again I created a symlink from /usr/include/glibmm to /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm, which is where ustring.h actually resides.

Now the compiler has stopped complaining about ustring.h, but the first (actual) line in ustring.h is

```
#include <glibmmconfig.h>
```

which the compiler cannot find.

The actual location of glibmmconfig.h is /usr/lib64/glibmm-2.4/include.  But I would prefer not to alter ustring.h.

Is there a way out of my problems without constantly having to create symlinks, etc.?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

I was able to get around my problems with the following compiler options:

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs glibmm-2.4 libxml++-2.6`
```

Thanks to jpalecek for pointing the way, but I had to hunt some more until I was able to get around my problem.

But while these compiler options compile the simple programme above, they fail to compile the tutorial on the [libxml++ tutorial page](http://developer.gnome.org/libxml++-tutorial/stable/chapter-parsers.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string FilePath = "SampleXMLDocument.xml";
    try {
        xmlpp::DomParser Parser;
        Parser.set_substitute_entities ();
        Parser.parse_file (FilePath);
        cout << "Successfully parsed XML file" << endl;
    } catch (const exception& excp) {
        cout << "Exception caught:  " << excp.what () << endl;
    }
    return 0;
} // End main ()
```

This time I get a bunch of errors like the following:

```
undefined reference to `xmlpp::DomParser::DomParser()`
undefined reference to `xmlpp::Parser::set_substitute_entities(bool)`
```

and so on.

I guess my search continues.

Comment: Which platform / distribution are you using?

Comment: Fedora 16, as mentioned in the post.  The output of "uname -a" is "Linux localhost.localdomain 3.3.2-1.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Apr 14 00:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Comment: What about add the path to your libraries? for example, path=...;path_to_your_h_files. I don't know if it works or I will post it as an answer

Comment: About the edit: Isn't your problem similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10200868/51831? Try that solution and see if it helps.

Comment: You edited to say that you are now using `pkg-config --cflags --libs glibmm-2.4 libxml++-2.6`. Note that you don't need to mention glibmm-2.4. Just mentioning libxml++-2.6 will take care of that for you. But I don't know why you still have those linker errors.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass correct options to the compiler, particularly a correct include path. The packagers have made that possible by a program that gives you the options: `xml++-config --cflags` will give you `-Ipath_to_headers`, `xml++-config --libs` will give you `-lto_link`.

Answer (score 0):

well i am not familiar with Fedora 16 but i think u got some link errors because libxml++ cannot be found.
1. check /usr/lib/ and other possible dirs that libxml++.so(maybe this name...) may locates. Make sure /etc/ld.so.conf contains this path so link can find it. If not, try to add the location of libxml++ and run "ldconfig" to update.
2. check the usage of -l option with the g++ is correct...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to compile a library depending on libxml++-X.X is to use pkg-config:

```
c++ -std=c++11 -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6) -o test main.cc
```

Specifying just libxml++-2.6 will resolve the glibmm-2.4 dependencies as well.